# Не удаляется файл с помощью file.delete() в Java

Tags: java, файлы

Не удаляется файл с помощью `file.delete()`. Ни папка, ни файл - ничего не удаляется даже отдельно.

```
public class DeleteFolderRecursively {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String folder = "/Users/prologistic/tmp";
        // удаляем файл рекурсивно
        recursiveDelete(new File(folder));
    }
     
    public static void recursiveDelete(File file) {
        // до конца рекурсивного цикла
        if (!file.exists())
            return;
         
        //если это папка, то идем внутрь этой папки и вызываем рекурсивное удаление всего, что там есть
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            for (File f : file.listFiles()) {
                // рекурсивный вызов
                recursiveDelete(f);
            }
        }
        // вызываем метод delete() для удаления файлов и пустых(!) папок
        file.delete();
        System.out.println("Удаленный файл или папка: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
 
}
```

Comment: Да нет, всё отлично удаляется. Проверьте правильность написания путей

Comment: Папка `/Users/prologistic/tmp` должна лежать в корне проекта. Это так?

Answer (score -1):

Файлы были открыты в другой программе. Из-за этого ничего не происходило.

Comment: Тогда должно было выскочить какое-нибудь исключение, наверное